# Как получить список процессов в osx и macOS

Tags: c++, qt, bash, macos, mac

Не владею данным устройством, к сожалению.
В маке по идее есть аналог командной строки, команды которой можно выполнить через *QProcess*
Для винды команда выглядит:

```
tasklist.exe /v /fo list
```

Для linux:

```
ps -e
```

А как будет выглядеть команда для macOS и OSX?
Если у кого есть яблоко - можете помочь?

Comment: macOS 10.15 - `ps -ec`, выдаст результат похожий на linux

Comment: @Exploding Kitten огромное спасибо

Comment: Если у кого есть osx - можете глянуть, будет ли работать

Comment: да, будет работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как и в любой posix-совместимой операционной системе — с помощью программы [*ps*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html).

список всех процессов можно получить, передав опцию `-A` или её эквивалет `-e`.

добавлением других опций можно изменять вид и количество выдаваемой программой информации.